# Codeigniter : image upload validation

Tags: jquery, html, css, codeigniter

i want to validate uploaded image, so when the `size` and the `type` not like the `config`, i want to show some alert or maybe an error message, i already trying something like below code but if the `size` or `type` not allowed instead of showing error message or alert, it just make the button unclickable, what am i doing wrong?, i've been search it all over the internet but i still don't get it cause i just recently learn `CI` and `PHP` not to mention english is not my first, i believe it can be done using `javascript` or in `controller` itself

> **CONTROLLER**

```
public function Upload($id){
    $upload = $this->input->post('fotoDsn');
    //Foto Set
    $photoName = gmdate("d-m-y-H-i-s", time()+3600*7).".jpg";
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/dosen/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif||jpg||png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['file_name'] = $photoName;
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){           
        $upload = 1;
    }else if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
        $upload = 2;
    }
    if($upload==1){
        $data   = array(
                'foto_dosen'=>$photoName);
        $insert = $this->MDosen->update(array('id'=>$id),  $data);
        if($insert){
            echo 1;
        }else{
            echo 2;
        }
    }else if($upload==2){//if upload fail
        alert('error');
        echo "failed";
        $errors = $this->upload->display_errors('<p>','failed try again','</p');
        flashMsg($errors);
    }
}
```

> **VIEW**

```
<!-- Upload Modal Structure Start -->
<div id="modalUpload" class="modal" style="width: 40%; height: auto">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
             <i class="medium material-icons prefix">assignment_ind</i>
                <h4 class="modal-title"> Upload Foto</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="upload" id="tambahFormUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="file-field input-field">
                        <div class="btn">
                            <span>File</span>
                            <input type="file" name="userfile">
                        </div>
                        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                            <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Simpan</button>
                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Upload Modal Structure End -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problem. It runs perfectly in `codeigniter-3.0.6`. After looking at the error log, I think the version of codeigniter you using has a bug.

> Reference here: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4137
>
> Fix is here: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/84f24c23baf5ea45c30c4ab3cbc57cd846ea0f56

I think you have to change the line number `190` of your `Exceptions.php` file located in `C:\xampp\htdocs\PETTA\system\core\Exceptions.php`

**From**

```
public function show_exception(Exception $exception)
```

**To**

```
public function show_exception($exception)
```

**Update**

I have tested your code again. Here is working copy of your code.

```
    function upload()
    {
        echo'<div id="modalUpload" class="modal" style="width: 40%; height: auto">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                     <i class="medium material-icons prefix">assignment_ind</i>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"> Upload Foto</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="'.base_url('costing/upload').'" id="tambahFormUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="file-field input-field">
                                <div class="btn">
                                    <span>File</span>
                                    <input type="file" name="userfile">
                                </div>
                                <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                                    <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Simpan</button>
                            </div>  
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>';



        // $upload = $this->input->post('fotoDsn');
            //Foto Set
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){
            $photoName = gmdate("d-m-y-H-i-s", time()+3600*7).".jpg";
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/dosen/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif||jpg||png';
            $config['max_size'] = '1000';
            $config['file_name'] = $photoName;
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){           
                $upload = 1;
            }else if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
                $upload = 2;
            }
            if($upload==1){
                // $data   = array(
                //         'foto_dosen'=>$photoName);
                // $insert = $this->MDosen->update(array('id'=>$id),  $data);
                // if($insert){
                //     echo 1;
                // }else{
                //     echo 2;
                // }
            }else if($upload==2){//if upload fail
                    
                // echo "failed";
                 $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
                 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                            alert("error, failed try again.'.$errors.'");
                            </script>';
                // flashMsg($errors);
            }
          }

    }
```

Because of i am busy doing another work, i didn't used any view file here, just one function in controller. You have to change the `form action="'.base_url('costing/upload').'"`  to your preferred controller/function, there is no input named `fotoDsn`, so i have commented this line : `$upload = $this->input->post('fotoDsn');`, also commented out database update part as i dont have the model or table, also updated the error reporting function as i don't know what the `flashMsg($errors)` function does. You have to modify these changes to suit your own.

Comment: i have edited it, if you can post errors, it will be very helpful solve the problem. thanks

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CI_Exceptions::show_exception() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\PETTA\system\core\Common.php on line 658 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\PETTA\system\core\Exceptions.php:190 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PETTA\system\core\Common.php(658): CI_Exceptions->show_exception(Object(Error)) #1 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PETTA\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 190 `, still got the same error

Comment: I have changed again, sorry for misunderstanding. if it have any further error, please post here.

Comment: no error right now, but the button become unclickable, i want when the rule is wrong it show an pop up message some kind like alert, and how can i do that? im gonna look into it later since i don't have much time rn, but this issue really bother me

Comment: you have to post the code of the form which has the button in it.